# Any workaround for the 32KB limit on data:uri in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, data-uri

I want to load a picture in a `HTML` `img` element on a button click through `JavaScript`. The `JavaScript` calls an `ActiveX` function and gets a BASE64 encoded, string representing the image, which it then puts in the `img` `src` like this:

```
var message = activex.GetImage(param);
var img = document.getElementById("imgPhoto").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64, ".concat(message);
```

The problem is I tested it in a recent `IE` with backwards compatibility to `IE8` and it worked, but the actual `IE8` has a 32KB restriction on `data:uri`, which means my picture gets cut off and only ~32KB of it are displayed.

Solutions:

1. I'm thinking of converting the `BMP`s to `JPEG`s, but I still can't guarantee that they won't exceed the limit.
2. I've also seen [this](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/) approach, where the image is loaded through `CSS` in `MHTML`, but I can't see how I could rewrite the `CSS` file every time. As I understand it, `JavaScript` can't really write files on your disk.

Anyone managed to get past this limitation, considering my restrictions?

Comment: Break the images up into smaller sections perhaps?

Comment: as second approach, as I understand you can create `<style>` element in js and add random id to the element you create, so you'll be able to setup data uri for this created element, it is bad if you need to switch image many times, but ok if you need it once.

Comment: I need to reload the image lots of times, but the JPEG solution worked fine for my problem. I had to use the HTML just as a proof of concept so that the client would see the image retrieval works and that they can integrate it in their environment. Thank you, anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest avoiding the use of BMP entirely - use JPEGs instead. You'll get much smaller file-sizes and far better performance. Not to mention, you'll come in under that 32kb limit more often than not. In the cases where 32kb is *still* not enough, it's often times the case that you can shave off a few more bytes by removing [unnecessary meta-data](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/14-10-03/hunting-for-unoptimized-images-with-fiddler) (common with apps like Adobe Photoshop) from the image file itself. In the event 32kb is still not enough after compression and removal of meta-data, I would suggest you consider again if a data URI is appropriate.